# How to align input and select form elements in one row

Tags: css, alignment

How can I align the `input` and `select` form elements in [my test case](http://jsfiddle.net/cizmazia/KMVmw/), so that their horizontal borders are aligned and all text including labels is aligned to the baseline?

I want to have a `label` and an `input` form element along with another `label` and a `select` form element *in one row*. Therefore I want to have *horizontal* borders of `select` and `input` elements aligned, and I also want to have all text including labels
aligned to the *baseline*. Is it possible?

I was unable to achieve it on IE8 or FF on Win. I tried `box-sizing:
border-box;` to force `input` and `select` to be rendered using the same
box model.

See [my test case](http://jsfiddle.net/cizmazia/KMVmw/), which has this code:

```html
<form action="Submit" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Sex<select><option value="" selected="selected">Sex</option></select></label>
        <label>Date of Birth<input type="text" value="Date of Birth" /></label>
    </p>
</form>
```

```css
body, input, select {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

select, input {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when I do not set the height of `select` and `input` elements then setting the `border` to `1px` gets it aligned. I do not change the default `vertical-align: baseline` to keep the *text baselines* aligned. I made it too complicated before. This short CSS did it:

```
body, input, select {
  font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

select, input { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

Comment: I added 'margin:0;' before 'border:1px solid gray;': since I have labels on top of each control, I prefer the same space vertically under each label (the select ends a little more down than the input but is less noticeable).

Answer (score 12):

I suggest adding this style to the `select` and `input` elements:

```css
vertical-align: bottom;
```

You can add padding to the `select` element. However, you will get some whitespace around the drop-down arrow. `2px` should be okay, but play around with it. This should help with the text baselines.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This aligns horizontal borders. However text baselines do not sit on the same line.

Comment: @michal you can add padding to the select element. however, you will get some whitespace around the drop-down arrow. 2px should be ok, but play around with it...

Comment: i edited my response, i don't think the line-height gives you any added benefit. best of luck...

Comment: Thanks. I do not know how to make all text including labels aligned to the baseline as well.